# как отправить несколько файлов c input type=file через ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax

столкнулся с проблемой что нужно отправить несколько файлов через ajax когда пользователь загрузил их через Input[type=file]. Проблема в том что у меня только отправляет только 1 файл например из 3-4 если забрасывать. Как можно отправить все

```
<input type="file" class="js-expodocupload-file"  multiple>

$(".js-expodocupload-file").change(function() {
 var self = $(this),
 fileList = [],
 fileInput = document.querySelector('.js-expodocupload-file'),
                    iconType = $(".js-doc-type-init").val(),
                    file_data = $(".js-expodocupload-file")[0].files,
                    form_data = new FormData();

                for (var x = 0; x < file_data.length; x++) {
                    form_data.append('files[]', file_data[x]);
                }
      $.ajax({
        url: '/admin/appbuilder/upload',
                    dataType: 'text',
                    cache: false,
                    contentType: false,
                    processData: false,
                    data: form_data,
                    type: 'post',
success: function(data) {
                        data = JSON.parse(data);
                        console.log(data);
}
      });
});
```

Comment: form_data.append('files[' + x + ']', file_data[x]);

Comment: XelaNimed спасибо, действительно в этом была ошибка

Answer (score 1):

```
var fd = new FormData();
fd.append('file0', input.files[0]);
fd.append('file1', input.files[1]);

$.ajax({
  url: '/admin/appbuilder/upload',
  data: fd,
  processData: false,
  contentType: false,
  type: 'POST',
  success: function(data){
    alert(data);
  }
});
```